# Magento 1.9 Pass value from html input field to email template in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, input

I have made a custom module to add some html input fields in Admin Order view. What I want to do is when clicking on the Send Email button in Order View, the information typed in the html input fields would be passed to the email template. How to make this possible?

My question is different from [Get my custom variable into an email template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119718) as I need to pass text from input fields directly to the email template. Please note the text in input fields is not saved in the DB.

Comment: could you share the screenshot here so that we can understand better thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by wrapping input field to a form. 
So it looks like this,

Form -> (pass data to) Controllers -> (pass data to) Email template